# Text wrap'ing [CSS]

Tags: css, text, word-wrap

I'm finishing my web site http://centrosokoladine.lt/ And how you can see there is in middle left some picture covered with text, and I need to wrap that text. Image is set like those box'es bakground image, no repeat left middle...

Here that exact part of html:

```
<div class="turinio"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

And css:

```
.vidinis
{
    background-color:#a68e84;
    layer-background-color:#a68e84;
    width: 709px;
    /* height: 306px; */
    align: center;
    padding-top: 17px;
    visibility: visible;
    **background-image: url('http://centrosokoladine.lt/wp-content/themes/sokoladine/grafika/info.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-position: bottom left;**
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I know that it's not posible wrap text arround background images so I'm looking for other solution here, maybe I already tried to create seperate div for that image, but I failed..

Comment: Hint:  Floating `div`'s were invented just for this.  (Text will wrap around them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with a background-image unless (1) You give a padding-bottom to your div and don't show text *next* to the image, or (2) you give a padding-left to your div and don't show text *under* the image.

An `img` element is the normal (html) way to do this. You can then add the `align` attribute to that image.

Comment: But for me it's kinda problematic how to set that image to that corner, okey I'll user align="left" and what then? Those boxes ins't fixed size, and I don't know how to move the image down, that it would always stay in that cornew and wrap..

Comment: I understand the problem, but the `img` tag (or a floated div as @Sparky672 sais) is the way to go to have text wrapping around it. To make sure it's in the bottom left corner, one option could be to measure the amount of text that needs to be wrapped on the right side, and then use jQuery to inject the image at the desired character position.

Comment: @Tauvydas you want to put a *position: relative* on the `div` and a *position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px* on the image

Comment: I probably coded my div's not properly, because I have tried it all and it ruins my design a lot, and never wraps :(

Answer (score 0):

```
float: left;
```

Float will do the trick.